# Symbolic values on a single axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a single axis with symbolic values on ticks:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=none,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$},
        xmin={[normalized]0},
        xmax={[normalized]5},
        xtickmax={[normalized]4},
        xtick distance=1]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where was I wrong? On the axis there is only x1

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `ymin` and `ymax` to avoid the empty range issue and the usage of the default range 0-1 for both the x- and the y-axis.

Example:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=none,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$},
        xmin={[normalized]0},
        xmax={[normalized]5},
        xtickmax={[normalized]4},
        xtick distance=1,
        ymin=0,ymax=0% <- added
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much @esdd! Your patience is infinity!